# binary count in C whit a button

Tags: c, button, binary, counter, gpio

```
printf("hello world\r\n");
fflush(stdout);
int number;
number = 0;
while (1)
{     


    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SW5_GPIO_Port,SW5_Pin)==GPIO_PIN_RESET){
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        number = number + 1 ;
        printf("number incremented with 1 is: %d\n",number);

    }
}
```

i need to create a binary counter with 1 button i have declared 4 leds before with the name:
LED5
LED6
LED7
LED8

if I click on the button I credit a number I have to convert this number to a binary value and display it on the given leds can you help me?

Yours sincerely

Comment: How does the posted code relate to what you need help with?

Comment: @ScottHunter I most likely is the teacher-provided empty frame in which to write the homework assignment.

Comment: Just on the off chance that this is homework related, please study the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I count an integer with my button SW 5

but I have to convert the integer value to a binary value and then display it on my leds: LED 5
LED6
LED7
LED8

BV: binary value 0101

then led 5 and 7 should light up  


I used a micro controller for this
stm32f411re
is the type        @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `&` and swift`<<` you can write this like:

```
if (number & 1) {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_5, 1);
} else {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_5, 0);
}
if (number & 1 << 1) {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_6, 1);
} else {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_6, 0);
}
if (number & 1 << 2) {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_7, 1);
} else {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_7, 0);
}
if (number & 1 << 3) {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_8, 1);
} else {
  AL_GPIO_WritePin(SW5_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_8, 0);
}
```

Not sure for the command to activate GPIO_PIN but the logic is here